# Angular submodule routes override each other if submodules depend on each other

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have an Angular app with the below structure.
it consists of an app module containing multiple submodules.
The submodules each have their own routing module which is imported in the submodule itself.
The submodules are then lazy loaded in the `AppRoutingModule`.

The routes should work like the following:

```
/foomodule -> ListComponent
/foomodule/:id -> DetailComponent

/barmodule -> ListComponent
/barmodule/:id -> DetailComponent
```

The problem now is when I have `FooModule` and `BarModule` with `BarModule` having a dependency on a component from `FooModule`, the routes of `FooModule` override `BarModule`.

So navigating to `/barmodule` triggers route component for `/foomodule` which should not be.

How can I solve this?
Do I have to use a module without routing?

AppModule:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
  ]
})
class AppModule {}
```

AppRouting:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "foomodule",
    loadChildren: FooModuleFactory,
  },
  {
    path: "barmodule",
    loadChildren: BarModuleFactory,
  },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

The submodules routing modules look all like this:

```js
// foomodule-routing.module.ts

const routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: ListComponent
  },
  {
    path: ":id",
    component: DetailsComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FooModuleRoutingModule {}

export function FooModuleRoutingFactory() {
  return FooModuleRoutingModule;
}
```

The related submodule:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FooModuleRouting,
  ]
})
export class FooModule {}
```

`BarModule` with dependency:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // FooModule routes will override BarModuleRoutingModule
    FooModule,
    BarModuleRoutingModule,
  ],
})
export class BarModule {}
```